# TypeError: tankImg.style is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

This web page should show a list of tanks in 'preview' and then I can choose > one element from this catalog by mouse click. After this newDoc() shoul return the page with tank details  when I click on someone element from list in console appears message

> "TypeError: tankImg.style is undefined", Firefox

```
//app.js
    function newDoc(event) {
        alert(this.className)
        var root = document.getElementById('root'),
            originTree = root.innerHTML;
        root.innerHTML = ''   


//create all needed element
    var previewBox1 = document.createElement('div'),
        previewBox2 = document.createElement('div'),
        previewCommon = document.createElement('div') ,
        tankImg = document.createElement('div'),
        previewLabel = document.createElement('div'),
        backToList = document.createElement('div'),
        table = document.createElement('div'),
        previewBox1Flag = document.createElement('div'),
        previewBox1Model = document.createElement('div'),
        previewBox1Level = 

document.createElement('div');

    // find tank object by Model name
    for (let i = 0; i < tanks.length; ++i){
        if (tanks[i].model === this.className){
            var clickedObj = tanks[i];
            break;
        }
    }


// fill by data object
    tankImg.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + clickedObj.preview + ")";
//in previous line is my trouble!
    previewBox1Flag.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + 
clickedObj["country_image"] + ")";
    previewBox1Level.innerHTML = "(level " + clickedObj.level + ")";
    previewBox1Model.innerHTML = clickedObj.model.toUpperCase();
    backToList.innerHTML = 'Back to list view';
    previewLabel.innerHTML = 'Preview';
    table.innerHTML = 'Characteristic';

//    to construck all the element 
    previewCommon.appendChild(previewBox1Flag);
    previewCommon.appendChild(previewBox1Model);
    previewCommon.appendChild(previewBox1Level);

    previewBox1.appendChild(previewCommon);
    previewBox1.appendChild(previewLabel);
    previewBox1.appendChild(tankImg);
    previewBox1.appendChild(backToList);
    previewBox2.appendChild(table);
    root.appendChild(previewBox1);
    root.appendChild(previewBox2);  
}

function makePreviewObject(list){
    var rootDiv = document.getElementById('root'),
        newUl = document.createElement('ul');
    for (let i = 0;i < list.length; ++i){

        var nextLi = document.createElement('li'),
            newImgDiv = document.createElement('div'),
            newCommonDiv = document.createElement('div'),
            divForFlag = document.createElement('div'),
            divForLevel = document.createElement('div'),
            divForModel = document.createElement('div');

        nextLi.className = list[i].model;
        newImgDiv.className = 'newImgDiv';
        newCommonDiv.className = 'newCommonDiv';
        divForFlag.className = 'divForFlag';
        newImgDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + list[i].preview + ')';
        divForFlag.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + list[i]['country_image'] 
+ ')';
        divForLevel.innerHTML = list[i].level;
        divForModel.innerHTML = lengthOffSet(list[i].model.toUpperCase());

        newCommonDiv.appendChild(divForFlag);
        newCommonDiv.appendChild(divForLevel);
        newCommonDiv.appendChild(divForModel);

        nextLi.addEventListener('click', newDoc);
        nextLi.appendChild(newImgDiv);
        nextLi.appendChild(newCommonDiv);

        newUl.appendChild(nextLi);

        rootDiv.appendChild(newUl); 
    }

}

function lengthOffSet(string){
    if (string.length < 14){
        return string
    } else{
        return string.substr(0, 11) + '...'
    }
}

makePreviewObject(tanks);


//tanks.js
var tanks = [
  {
    model: "Object 140",
    preview: "images/tanks/object_140.png",
    country: "ussr",
    country_image: "images/countries/ussr.png",
    level: 10,
    details: {
      damage: 420,
      breoning: 264,
      attack_speed: 9.09,
      time_of_targeting: 2.1,
      ammunition: 50
    }
  },
  {
    model: "t-62a",
    preview: "images/tanks/t62a.png",
    country: "ussr",
    country_image: "images/countries/ussr.png",
    level: 10,
    details: {
      damage: 630,
      breoning: 246,
      attack_speed: 9.09,
      time_of_targeting: 2,
      ammunition: 50
    }
  }
]



//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="tanks.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Is this the code you are using, _unedited_? If so, it won't work because of your first line - `function newDoc[enter image description here][1](event) {`

Comment: Yes, I've missed it. There must be <function newDoc(event) {>